# LLDB Memory or read write on runtime

Tags: lldb

After playing around with lldb, I want to explore a way to write a register or memory value when a condition applies (breakpoint) automatically.

Does lldb have a feature like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lldb breakpoints have conditions and commands.  The condition (`-c` option to `break set` or `break modify`) is a C (ObjC/C++) expression evaluated in the frame context of the breakpoint hit.

The commands (added with `breakpoint command add`) only get run if the condition evaluates to true.  So if you can express the condition as an expression and the action as a sequence of fixed lldb commands, then you can implement the behavior you want that way.

You can also write breakpoint commands in Python (`breakpoint command add -s python` using the SB API's:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/index.html

so if you have a more complex condition under which you want to make your changes, or more complex actions, you can do those tasks with the Python API's.

Comment: I was able to print the entire registers with print lldb.frame.registers, but how can I print just one register, x0?

Comment: That's a separate question, a bit hard to answer in a comment....  Briefly, the frame's "register" object is an SBValueList.  Each element in the list has a name -use that to find the set you want.  The first element of the list is the GPR registers.  The register sets are stored as SBValues, with each actual register being a child of the value.  You can look them up by name or index.  So for instance `lldb.frame.registers[0].GetChildMemberWithName("x0")` prints the value of x0.  See the docs on SBValueList at https://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/lldb.SBValueList-class.html for more info.